# hide element with javascript progressive enhancement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use Jquery toggle method to view a div when a button is clicked

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#divId").toggle();
});
```

Works fine but the initial value is set to be viewed or as the css property       `display:block` so when the page initially loads the div is viewed and I have to click the button to close it.

what other answers suggested is that I change the css property but I do not want that as that will hide the div and if the user had their javascript not working for any reason, that would not be good.

So I want to hide the div initially with javascript and then comes Jquery's toggle method working normally. I tried `document.getElementById(divId).style.dsplay="none"` and put it right before the toggle method, but that makes the toggle not work and just hides the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set initial value to hide the div by this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#divId").hide();
   $("button").click(function(){
     $("#divId").toggle();
   });
});
```

After you click the button. it will toggle to open the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to hide div on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divId").hide(); //or .toggle()
});
```

**[UPDATE]**

Or if you have more advanced logic on *click* event and you want it to also run on load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").trigger('click');
});
```